# Communication between aggregates in DDD in appointment example

Tags: c#, .net, architecture, domain-driven-design

I have three Aggregate in my DDD app, Doctor,Patient,Schedule.
schedule aggregate manages appointments of doctors and patients.
doctor has a weekly schedule. I create a Weekly schedule Entity In My Doctor Aggregate.
in my schedule aggregate I have SetAppointment method, this method set Appointment according to Doctor Weekly Schedule.

```
public class WeeklySchedule : Entity
{
    public int DoctorId { get; set; }
    public DayOfWeek DayOfWeek { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan StartTime { get; set; }
    public TimeSpan EndTime { get; set; }
}
```

```
public class Doctor : AggregateRoot
{
    public string FirstName { get; }
    public string LastName { get; }
    public DoctorType DoctorType { get; set; }

    public List<WeeklySchedule> WeeklySchedule { get; set; }
    
    protected Doctor()
    {
        
    }

    public Doctor(string firstName,string lastName)
    {
        FirstName = firstName;
        LastName = lastName;
    }

    public bool IsRequestedDateInDoctorWeeklySchedule(DateTime date)
    {
        
    }   
    
    public List<WeeklySchedule> DoctorWeeklySchedule(long doctorId)
    {
        
    }
}
```

```
public class Schedule : AggregateRoot
{
    private Schedule()
    {
        
    }
    
    private readonly List<Appointment> _appointments = new List<Appointment>();
    public IEnumerable<Appointment> Appointments => _appointments.AsReadOnly();
    public long DoctorId { get; set; }
    public long PatientId { get; set; }

    public Schedule(long doctorId,long patientId)
    {
        DoctorId = doctorId;
        PatientId = patientId;
    }

    public bool SetAppointment()
    {
        
    }
}
```

**my questions is:**

1. how can I pass doctor weekly schedule from doctor aggregate to schedule aggregate according to DDD principles and best practices.
2. Where should I implement set appointments Process all steps:
   **a.** get patient information
   **b.** is requested appointment date according to doctor weekly schedule.
   **c.** set appointment
   (Where should I implement these steps? (in application service or aggregates)) ... Thank you for explaining with the code snippet

Comment: What is the Appointment object? Why did you define WeeklySchedule entity? Why did you model the Schedule as an AggregateRoot? Your domain is a myth to responders.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score -1):

Conceptually, it looks well-structured. However, as we dive deeper into the business rules, we might find opportunities to optimize the design.

Specifically, regarding the WeeklySchedule entity, it could potentially be inferred from the Schedule entity, depending on the exact business rules you already defined. Before making a final decision, it would be helpful to have a comprehensive list of business rules to ensure that the model meets all the requirements.